# Как поставить по умолчанию скрипт для открытия файла в Ubuntu 18.04 на GUI Gnome?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

Это было в более ранних версия Gnome. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас в 18.04 я не могу запустить скрипт для открытия файла
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: создайте desktop-файл для нужного mime-типа. пример файла можно найти [поиском по сайту](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=xdg-open)

Answer (score 1):

1. узнайте mime-тип файла:

   ```
   $ xdg-mime query filetype /путь/к/файлу
   ```
2. создайте desktop-файл `~/.local/share/applications/какое-нибудь-имя.desktop` (каталог надо создать, если не существуют) следующего содержания:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Exec=/путь/к/вашей/программе/или/скрипту %U
   Terminal=false
   MimeType=mime-тип-файла
   Name=какое-нибудь-имя
   ```

   (вместо `%U` при запуске вашей программы/скрипта будет подставлен путь к«открываемому» файлу)
3. назначьте созданный `какое-нибудь-имя.desktop` умолчальным обработчиком для указанного mime-типа файла:

   ```
   $ xdg-mime default какое-нибудь-имя.desktop mime-тип-файла
   ```

   эта команда добавит в файл `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` строку в секции `[Default Applications]` (и секцию добавит, если не было):

   ```
   [Default Applications]
   mime-тип-файла=какое-нибудь-имя.desktop
   ```

   при желании можно добавить эту строку (строки) и вручную. или воспользоваться тем графическим диалогом, который вы привели в вопросе (чтобы в нём появилось имя вашего desktop-файла, вероятно, надо будет переинициализировать базу mime-типов, что проще всего сделать, перезапустив x-сессию).